# How to replace/modify something in a call to function 1 from within function 2 (both in their separate files)

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, matrix-multiplication, matrix-inverse

The given task is to call a function from within another function, where both functions are handling matrices.

Now lets call this function 1 which is in its own file:

`A = (1/dot(v,v))*(Ps'*Ps);`

Function 1 is called with the command:

```
bpt = matok(P);
```

Now in another file in the same folder where function 1 is located (matok.m) we make another file containing function 2 that calls function 1:

```
bpt = matok(P);
```

What I wish B to do technically, is to return the result of the following (where D is a diagonal matrix):

IGNORE THIS LINE:    `B = (1/dot(v,v))*(Ps'*inv(D)*Ps*inv(D);`

EDIT: this is the correct `B = (1/dot(v,v))*(Ps*inv(D))'*Ps*inv(D);`

But B should not "re-code" what has allready been written in function 1, the challenge/task is to call function 1 within function 2, and within function 2 we use the output of function 1 to end up with the result that B gives us. Also cause in the matrix world, A*B is not equal to B*A, then I can't simply multiply with inv(D) twice in the end. Now since Im not allowed to write B as is shown above, I was thinking of replacing (without altering function 1, doing the manipulation within function 2):

```
(Ps'*Ps)
```

with

```
(Ps'*inv(D)*Ps*inv(D)
```

which in some way I imagine should be possible, but since Im new to Matlab have no idea how to do or where even to start. Any ideas on how to achieve the desired result?

A small detail I missed:

The transpose shouldn't be of Ps in this:

```
B = (1/dot(v,v))*(Ps'*inv(D))*Ps*inv(D);
```

But rather the transpose of Ps and inv(D):

```
B = (1/dot(v,v))*(Ps*inv(D))'*Ps*inv(D);
```

I found this solution, but it might not be as compressed as it could've been and it seems a bit unelegant in my eyes, maybe there is an even shorter way?:

```
C = pinv(Ps') * A
E = (Ps*inv(D))' * C
```

Comment: Is `Ps` and `P` the same? Where does `v` come from?

Comment: No Ps and P are not the same, Ps is calculated from P in other lines of code.
v is just a columnvector of ones.

Comment: Without knowing where `Ps` comes from, this seems impossible. Could you provide a minimal example?

Comment: I'd also like a minimal working example.

Comment: you can just try to pass in D and use nargin to create a default D of eye(size) when no D is provied.

Comment: Ps is just a centered version of P. 
So Ps comes from yet another function that computes it, and it has been verified it is correct.

Comment: Ps is achieved by centering the orthogonal projections (in 2 different function files) of the columns of P onto a concrete vector (in this case our vector of ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since (A*B)' = B'*A', you probably just need to call

```
matok(inv(D) * Ps)
```

Comment: Didn't work, adding that returned the error. Also tried, which I think would be more correct in order to reflect the order in B: matok(Ps*inv(D)), which returned the same errror:
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: Found out why it didn't work, cause inner dim didn't match between Ps' and D, which was a small overlooked detail:


A small detail I missed (updated in main post):

The transpose shouldn't be of Ps in this

``B = (1/dot(v,v))*(Ps'*inv(D))*Ps*inv(D);`

But rather the transpose of both Ps and inv(D)

'B = (1/dot(v,v))*(Ps*inv(D))'*Ps*inv(D);'

I found this solution, but it might not be as compressed as it could've been and it seems a bit unelegant in my eyes, maybe there is an even shorter version?:

'C = pinv(Ps') * A'
'E = (Ps*inv(D))' * C'